# Vuejs 2 router not working programatically but, working as router link

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**index js file**

I used vue router programatically but it didn't working for me.I searched through the web and everyone used `this.$router.push()`.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import BecomeHost from '@/components/BecomeHost'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
 routes: [
 {
  path: '/',
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  component: HelloWorld
 },
 {
  path: '/become_host',
  name: 'BecomeHost',
  component: BecomeHost
 }
]})
```

**component.vue**

I called like below when response sucess but not working

```
if (res.data.status === 'success') {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.data.data))
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    this.setUserData(user)
    this.$router.push('/become_host')
}
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, can you explain a bit more? What's doing or not doing? Is it going through $router.push? Do you have any error in the console?

Answer (score 2):

you can try it like below

```
this.$router.push({path: 'become_host'})
// or
this.$router.push('BecomeHost')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use push with props, more details [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

In your case I think, you need something like this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: 'become_host' })
```

OR

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'BecomeHost' })
```